# Cannot access form values via HTTP POST value in controller using jQuery's .serialize() in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am facing a problem with posting a form using the jQuery `.serialize()` method. When the form is passed to the jQuery function, it can get all the values via HTTP POST, but when using the `.serialize()` method to send the form to the controller, the controller can't get the values. Here is my code:

In View:

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post">
Email: <input type="text" class="contactStyle required email" id="email" name="email"/>
Password:<input type="password" class="contactStyle required" id="password" name="password"/>
</form>
<a href='#' onclick="login(); return false;" class="loginBut" >Login</a>
```

Javascript code:

```
login = function(){
.post(base_url + "elements/ajax_login",  $("#loginForm").serialize(),
function(data){
if(data.success == 'success'){
   top.location =  top.location;
}else if(data.success == 'admin'){
   top.location = base_url + "admin";
}else if(data.success == 'failed'){
          alert('Incorrect login');
          //ADD POPUP
          $('#warn').hide().html('Your email / password combination is not correct.').show('slow');
}else{
    alert("An error has occured please try refreshing the page.")
}
},'json');
}
```

Controller:

```
function ajax_login() {
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $result = array();

    if ($this->ion_auth->login($email, $this->input->post('password'), 0)) { //if the login is successful
        //if its an admin send them to the dashboard
        if ($this->ion_auth->is_admin()) {
            $result['success'] = 'admin';
        } else {                
            $result['success'] = 'success';
        }
    } else { //if the login was un-successful
        $result['success'] = 'failed';            
    }
    echo json_encode($result);

}
```

I got the error in the first step that passing the value from the View to jQuery is Method Post but when passing value from jquery to controller it uses Method Get.

Comment: What happens when you do print_r($_POST) in your controller?

Comment: In controller it does not get any value from form.

Comment: Just a guess but youre missing the `$` before `.post` e.g. `$.post()` Also. There is no reason to serialize the form if you use jquery's `$.ajax();` and post itll auto send the values.

Comment: have you attempted alert($(#loginForm).serialize()); This will tell you if your login function is being called and if the inputs are being serialized.

Answer (score 1):

try instead seralizeArray:

```
$.post(base_url + "elements/ajax_login",  $("#loginForm").serializeArray(),
function(data){
    // all your stuff
},'json');
```